# Get the local machine's current format setting of long-time and short-time

Tags: powershell, time, format

I am trying to use powershell to get the local machine's format setting for long and short time.

In other words I want to know what the current setting of "long time" is as listed in Start Menu(win 10) Settings->Time&Language->ChangeDateTimeFormats

Expecting to get back 'H:MM:SS' or similar

Part of the reason I want this info is I'd like to know if machine is set to 24 hour time or needs to be.

Is this possible? I have looked around the web a ton and seem to only find examples of using Get-Date with 'your specified format'. Nothing that 'retrieves' the current format setting.

Comment: (Off topic) [Here's another SE site](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) that may interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern` seems to have what you need. It will start with a capital 'H' if the machine is set for 24-hour format. 
[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1201188/how-do-i-change-date-time-format-via-command-prompt-powershell) is a related question and answer.